# Update gauge dial with fusionCharts and AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I have a **FusionChart** gauge that I want to update every second in **Angularjs**I have a json object with values that I want to use to update the gauge with.
I think that I proplably should use the function "setData(dialIndex, value)" somehow.
I know how to create a interval but not how to use the update function for the dail.

```
app.controller('StartController',function($scope...
    $scope.dataSource = {
        "chart": {
            ...
            "dials": {
                "dial": [
                {
                  "value": "65",
                   ...
                }]
            }
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/9ttz2287/) might help you. Basically you need to get the instance of that particular FusionCharts and need to call its API method (`setData` or `feedData`)